# C++ WinRT Playback SpeechSynthesisStream via MediaPlayer::Play() requires some waiting, doesn't it?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, text-to-speech, windows-media-player

I'm trying to playback SpeechSynthesisStream via MediaPlayer in main thread using the code below(minimal example):

```
void SpeakStream(winrt::Windows::Media::Playback::MediaPlayer& media, winrt::Windows::Media::SpeechSynthesis::SpeechSynthesisStream& sse)
{
    auto source = winrt::Windows::Media::Core::MediaSource::CreateFromStream(sse, sse.ContentType());
    
    media.Source(source);
    media.Play();

    //Sleep(5000);
    
    source.Close();
    media.Close();
}
```

The problem is that if I do not block thread after calling Play() (like commented Sleep() call), I don't hear sound. Blocking thread helps, but obviously that is not correct solution and I want to know why it happens and how to correctly implement this.

Comment: It looks thread problem, you may need to call play method in UI thread, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2).

Comment: Actually, it is already called in UI thread.

Comment: Could you mind share [mcve] for us?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SpeechSynthesisStream. Interestinlgy enough your question helped my to solve my own issue with SpeechSynthesisStream, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you close media and source before it could play the source, Play is not a blocking call.
You could add media.Close() to the destructor of your class, you should not close that after each Play call.
Almost the same with the source. If you call media.Source repeatedly, you can decide if you want to add the new content to the end of the current strem, or you want to close the previous stream and change the media source to the new one.
If you want to block the thread until media is finished i.e. before returning from a thread, you can subscribe to the MediaEnded event.

Comment: Thank you, I got about media and source closing. I've tried to subscribe to MediaEnded event. So, I subscribe, call play(), then WaitForSingleObj(hMediaEnded). Where hMediaEnded is event that I set in MediaEnded handler. I've also tried to subscribe on MediaOpened event. And even MediaOpened fires after playback ended. Is there any rules that I should run playback and handle event in different thread or something?